# Cannot access secondary router from primary

Tags: networking

I bought a second router and I set it up using LAN/WAN configs. From the secondary router clients, I can ping and access clients on primary router. But from the primary router, I cannot access any clients on secondary router. **I cannot even ping the second router IP address.**

Primary router IP: 192.168.100.1
Secondary router IP: 192.168.100.2 and 192.168.0.1
DHCP enabled on second router: 192.168.0.2-100

Ping from 192.168.100.1 to 192.168.100.2 passed only when I enabled "enable wan response" option.

But I cannot ping 192.168.0.1. I dont understand why clients from 192.168.0.0/24 network can access 192.168.100.0/24 network but the reverse cannot be achieved. Tried disabling firewall and security in router 2 but did not work.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If your pings are going through 192.168.0.1 (DHCP) you should add a route on the secondary router (assuming on Linux):

```
router2$ route add -net 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. The primary router is a huawei and the other is a dlink router. I tried to add routes but it is not working. I re-configured the network as one network (lan to lan). It is working now.